# I found the "<<" at one script and I want to know how it works

Tags: php

I found `<<` in a php script and I want to know how it works;

eg:

```
echo 2 << 4;
```

it prints 32

Comment: [It is a binary left shift.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: Did you try looking it up [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)?

Comment: `<<` is a bitshift operator in c++, same in php, 2 moved 4 bits left = 32.  In theory a bitshift is a very cheap operation to carry out, as it is a bitwise manipulation as opposed to multiplying for example which is an instruction which has to compute an answer.  With a bitshift the answer is implicit in the original value.  From a programming point of view I always prefer `2 << 4` to `2*2^4` as `2<<4` is much much faster than the alternative. (NB I have not tested the speed of each on php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shift left**

From the php.net manual on [Bitwise Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

---

`2 << 4` means `2 * 2^4 = 32`